# HTML Email display issues in yahoo/gmail

Tags: html, html-email, monitor

Having real issues with an email mailer I need to send out to my client today. It's not displaying properly in Yahoo. The body appears to dissapear past the left and right margins.

Please find attached link to the test results.

http://hybridcom.createsend.com/screens/r/A7AD7F4FFF5E836B

and link to the live email -

http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/Eblasts/Mercy%20Schools/index.html

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9Dvg5/embedded/result/

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jsFiddle link to send as demo.

Its like demonstrating the actual website with editable code.

[**Here is your the Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Dvg5/embedded/result/)